# A wordsmith's bravado

Tags: riddle, knowledge, literature

The following clues lead to a famous quote.  Can you tell me what the quote is, and how you got there?

> - Emily Dickinson has decided that something of ours is swiss.
> - Laura Regan's 2002 one-liner
> - Moby Dick's 7th
> - Who takes George Foreman's tears?
> - Oscar Wao's Brief first word
> - A conflicting conjunction
> - A-ha's juicy first word
> - Who's father art in heaven?
> - Yogi Berra's advice, regarding what to do with forks.
> - 1984's slavery
> - Peter's mother's sister, and his daughter

Hints:

> - All clues lead to one word (or a contraction).
>  - The clues are not in order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since we've taken to partial answers for this, here are some question_asker does not yet have (at time of original writing):

Emily Dickinson has decided that something of ours is swiss.

> our **lives** are Swiss

Moby Dick's 7th

> Call me Ishmael. Some years ago - **never** mind how long precisely

Oscar Wao's Brief first word

> **Our** hero was not one of those Dominican cats

A conflicting conjunction

> **but**

A-ha's juicy first word

> "The Juicy Fruit Song" was the original title of "**Take** On Me"

Peter's mother's sister, and his daughter

> Spider-Man's Aunt **May**, after whom he named a daughter

---

The remaining words, courtesy of question_asker:

> 1984's slavery is **freedom**
>  Yogi Berra suggests you **take** any forks you come to in the road
>  **our** father, who art in heaven
>  **They** (2002), starring Laura Regan
>  "**They'll** take everything, even your tears." —George Foreman

---

This gives the words needed for the quote (again, courtesy of question_asker):

> "They may take our lives, but they'll never take our freedom" —Braveheart (get it? Bravado??)

Comment: I managed to get some of these while you were typing this up - you got a better answer for Oscar Wao than my guess.

Comment: I think you could say we're just [a certain Newbery Medal winner]

Comment: lol, I was actually referring to the one word left. the fact that it isn't there + the word itself = a book title, which also makes sense if put into my comment above. sorry.

Comment: @question_asker OH. Got it. Spider Man, though.

Comment: OH FOR CRYING OUT L--

Comment: @question_asker I switched literary genres on you.  I actually meant to use anime for one of them, but I forgot.  Mua ha ha ha

Comment: OK so - I swooped in on an answer yesterday and I still feel a little bad about it. Feel free to incorporate my answer into yours for the checkmark if you like.

Comment: Nice jobs, both of you.  @question_asker I'll get you, next time, Batman!

Answer (score 9):

Partial answer

> 1984's slavery is **freedom**
>  Yogi Berra suggests you **take** any forks you come to in the road
>  **our** father, who art in heaven
>  **They** (2002), starring Laura Regan
>  ***Take*** On Me, a song once known as 'The Juicy Fruit Song'
>  **but**, the conflicting conjunction!
>  "**They'll** take everything, even your tears." —George Foreman
>  <s>I don't know if the first word of the *book* is "life", but the *title* of the book is *The Brief Wondrous **Life** of Oscar Wao*</s>
>  *Our **lives** are Swiss* is a poem by Emily Dickinson
>
>  *I think I see where this is going*
>
>  "They may take our lives, but they'll never take our freedom" —**Braveheart** (get it? Bravado??)

Comment: No cheating.  Figure out the rest before you tell the answer.  Haha, you're quick!

Comment: Too late. I'm a big old cheatyboi

Comment: @charfellow I found it in alex_salmond_quotes.txt